# Custom URL Scheme for Adobe Fill & Sign

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, adobe

I want my app to call the Adobe Fill & Sign app directly. I am able to do this with Adobe Acrobat Reader as it has an established and known app URL scheme, com.adobe.adobe-reader:// however, it's not clear what the equivalent custom URL scheme might be for Fill & Sign.
I tried com.adobe.FillAndSign:// with no success.
Thanks in advance.